Morse function on a two sphere
For the past few days I've been studying the very basics of Morse theory and its connection to supersymmetric quantum mechanics. I'm following the lectures written by David Tong. To introduce the basics of Morse theory he used a simple example of a two-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ together with the height function $h = z$, which is thus taken to be the Morse function. It says that there are then two critical points, namely the bottom and top of the sphere. I understand it untill now, however it then says that the Morse index of the bottom of the sphere is $\mu = 0$, whereas the Morse index of the top of the sphere is $\mu = 2$. I understand the definition of the Morse index as the amount of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian, however I don't seem to know how to how to compute the hessian for this sphere and incorporate the Morse/height function into it. Does anybode have a tip on how to understand this value of the Morse index? Any help would be greatly appreciated :))
P.s.: This is explained on page 86 of the lecture notes on supersymmetric quantum mechanics of David Tong which are freely available online

Just think about the Taylor expansion of $z=f(x,y)=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ at the origin.

A tip for the Morse functions on surfaces is that at the minimum value point, the index is $0,$ correspondingly at the maximum value point, the index is $2.$ You may think the index of the Morse function to be the number of different line-directions where the value of the function shall decrease starting at this point along the line.
